# Opencv discrete fourier transformation coordinates

Tags: c++, opencv, dft

In the implementation of DFT(for 2D) in opencv what coordinate system they use(Cartesian coordinate system or 2D array like coordinate system)?

(-1, 1)(0, 1)(1, 1) 
(-1, 0)(0, 0)(1, 0) 
(-1,-1)(0,-1)(1,-1)

(0,0)(0,1)(0,2)  
(1,0)(0,1)(0,2)  
(2,0)(0,1)(0,2)

Comment: Why does this matter to you? Remember, the assumption behind a DFT is that the input is periodic anyway. The sample at (-1,-1) is assumed to be the same as the one at (N-1, N-1). That said, it's easy to find the origin: take the IDFT of a constant signal.

Comment: My algorithm uses Cartesian one. So far I got an error values in calculating the frequency of peaks(I calculate amplitude, frequency, phase and the direction). I wonder it is an issue with coordinate system used in DFT.

Comment: Both coordinate systems are Carthesian (which just means you have orthogonal X and Y coordinates). As I said: find the DC point by transforming a DC input, that's trivial.

Comment: This is getting confusing. Let's forget about Cartesian thing. For dft() we just input an Mat. We have no control over coordinates. DFT algorithm gets the pixel coordinates(i,j) as input. As I illustrated(whatever the name it uses) (i,j) is different to each other. I think you got my point. I am a novel in image processing. Plz help